# Rails: displaying dropdown menu of collection.select

Tags: drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails app, I am displaying subcategories in dropdown list.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :product_sub_categories do |product_sub_category| %>
     <%= product_sub_category.collection_select :sub_category_id, @sub_categories, :id, :sub_category, {:include_blank => 'Select a Sub Category'} %>
      <% if @product.product_sub_categories.size > 1%>
       <%= product_sub_category.link_to_remove "Remove", :class => "subcatlink" %>
      <%end%>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.link_to_add 'Add', :product_sub_categories, "data-association-insertion-node"=> ".product_sub_categories",  "data-association-insertion-position" => "append", "data-type" => "link", :class => "subcatlink"%>
```

But it is not displaying dropdown list by default. When user click on 'Add' link, then it displays dropdown list.

I guess it is not entering in loop "f.fields_for :product_sub_categories do |product_sub_category|"

How to write a code so it will display one dropdown menu and will add other menus by clicking on 'Add'?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an initial (unsaved) instance of the child to the parent object so that when it renders the children it will render a single blank form before the add link.

You can choose to only do so if the parent has no children, or to always do so to force a blank form to always appear. For example:

Controller:

```
def edit
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
  @parent.sub_categories << SubCategory.new if @parent.sub_categories.blank? # only if no children already
  # or 
  @parent.sub_categories << SubCategory.new # always
end
```